# <end ckpt> in Recovery in DBMS

Tags: database, recovery, checkpoint

I have a following log at point of crash:

```
1 <start T1>
2 <T1, D, 20>
3 <commit T1>
4 <start T4>
5 <T4, B, 15>
6 <T4, A, 20>
7 <commit T4>
8 <start T2>
9 <T2, B, 12>
10 <start T3>
11 <T3, A, 30>
12 <T2, D, 25>
<- system crash
```

The question is that:
1) We begin a nonquiescent checkpoint immediately after one of the following log records has been written (in memory):

a) `2 <T1, D, 20>`

b) `5 <T4, B, 15>`

c) `9 <T2, B, 12>`

d) `11 <T3, A, 30>`

2) How far back in the log we must look to find all possible incomplete
transactions. And what values written by T1, T2, T3 and T4 after recovery?

In 1a , I was able to put the `<end ckpt>` after the `<Commit T1>` line.

In 1b , I was able to put the `<end ckpt>` after the `<Commit T2>` line.

However, the system crashed without committing T2 and T3, how could I solve 1c and 1d?

Moreover, I don't know what does "how far back" in question 2 mean. Can you suggest me a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

"How far back" means when you scan backwards, which line is enough for you to stop scanning more.
Each question you should consider both undo and redo cases. In undo case, we cannot insert  at question 1c and 1d because T2 and T3 are not committed. In redo case, the time when  is inserted depends on when the data written by T1 and T4 reached disk.
Besides, is this a homework called HW04?

Comment: Yes it is. I was wrong when I only check the redo method. Thanks for the help.